# Spring Data REST search methods return empty body when not results found

Tags: spring-data-rest

When performing a search using one of the `/{repository}/search/{method}` search methods, if the search parameters result in an empty result, the response is an empty body. This can cause problems with an Ajax application that always expects a value JSON response. Is there a way to return an empty JSON response instead of returning nothing. The following is the type of `Repository` definition I'm talking about.

```
public UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRespository<User, Long>
{
   public User findByUsername(@Param("username")String username);
}
```

In the above, if you do a `/users/search/findByUsername?username=foobar` you will get an empty response with a status code of 200. What I would like to do is return a 200 status code with a body of `{}`.

Ideally, I would prefer NOT to have to override the controller handling and re-implement all of the work that SDR already provides.

Answer (score 1):

By design SDR is doing it right way. However if you need a response all the time (empty or some results) change the definition of your search methods to return a collection. Something like below and do necessary work on the client side.

```
public UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRespository<User, Long>
{
   public List<User> findByUsername(@Param("username")String username);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think it can be argued that SDR is NOT performing correctly, at least in the case where it is returning a Content-Type of application/hal+json. According to the spec, all HAL documents at a minimum are required to return an empty JSON document, ```{}```. See http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html